# double pointer help me

Tags: c

in visuals studio i try to make respectively sum of rows. but first sum multiplied by 4 . i didnt understand this situation

```
get_sum(int **q, int p, int n);

int main(void)
{
    int num[3][5] = { 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 };
    get_sum(&num[0][0], 3, 5);
}
get_sum(int **q, int p, int n)
{
    /*for (int i = 0; i < ; i++)
    printf("%d\n", *(q + i));*/

    for (int k = 0; k < p; k++)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum =*(q + n*k + i)+sum;
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: when you pass your 2D-array to your get-sum function why are you using a double pointer? i think you are a bit confused. look here http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you simply want to create a function that sums the elements of the array passed as a parameter, along with the dimensions of the array, then you have the right idea, but woefully wrong syntax.

Rather than verbally discussing each change, the simple example contains all the changes. Look over the changes and why they were made:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_sum (int (*q)[5], int p, int n);

int main (void)
{
    int num[3][5] = {{ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 },
                     { 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 },
                     { 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 }};

    int sum = get_sum (num, 3, 5);
    printf ("   -----------\n    sum : %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}

int get_sum (int (*q)[5], int p, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < p; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sum += q[k][i];
        printf ("row[%2d] : %d\n", k, sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

(**note:** the loop output within `get_sum` provides are running-total of the `sum` after the addition of each row elements. You can tailor this to meet your needs.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/get_sum
row[ 0] : 60
row[ 1] : 145
row[ 2] : 255
   -----------
    sum : 255
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing a 1-D array as if it is a 2-D array, but there is no need to define it as 2-D, and anyway, you initialise it as if it were a 1-D array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_sum(int *q, int p, int n);                                 // only one start

int main(void)
{
    int num[] = { 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 };   // 1-D linear array
    get_sum(num, 3, 5);
    return 0;
}

void get_sum(int *q, int p, int n)                                  // added return type
{
    int k, i, sum;
    for (k = 0; k < p; k++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum = *(q + n*k + i) + sum;
        }
        printf("%d\n", sum);                                        // moved out of inner loop
    }
}
```

Program output

```
60
85
110
```

Alternatively if you do want a 2-D array and then index into it as if it were a 1-D array, you can do this. Note I have initialised the array differently but `get_sum` is the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_sum(int *q, int p, int n);                                 // only one start

int main(void)
{
    int num[3][5] = {{10,11,12,13,14}, {15,16,17,18,19}, {20,21,22,23,24}};
    get_sum(&num[0][0], 3, 5);
    return 0;
}

void get_sum(int *q, int p, int n)                                  // added return type
{
    int k, i, sum;
    for (k = 0; k < p; k++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum = *(q + n*k + i) + sum;
        }
        printf("%d\n", sum);                                        // moved out of inner loop
    }
}
```